# Eclipse or Maven creates bin directory - trouble with .launch files

Tags: eclipse, maven, teamcity

I have a maven project (main) with two modules (each module has this main project as its parent). Everything works perfect but last week I noticed that I can store the launch configurations from eclipse into regular *.launch files.

So I created a folder under main like : main/conf

where I store all my run configurations (*.launch). But after a while I noticed that eclipse or maven creates a **bin** direcotry under the main project (main/bin) with an exact copy of the main project (including pom.xml and .project file).

The other both projects doesn't have this directory.

The problem is, that eclipse scans the whole direcotry tree for *.launch files and eclipse finds them in main/conf and main/bin/conf.

I thought that the assembly plugin from maven might be the problem and removed that but without any luck. I am not sure if this is a problem with maven because I have teamcity building my jars and on my build agents are no bin direcotries. So it might be a problem with eclipse?

Thanks,
Hauke

Comment: Could you add the information, what contents the java build path for that project has? Normally only the contents of the directories that are source directories (under the folder `Source` in the properties of your project) are copied to the `bin` directory, so I assume that your project root is part of the build path for eclipse.

Comment: In Eclipse -> Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source is only project/src. In that folder are only some txt files (thats okay). The other tabs looks good for me too. Strange for me, if I modify one file outside the bin directory and look at the content of the corresponding file inside the bin direcotry, it is the same. Looks like a linux symbolic link. If I remove the bin direcotry it comes back after compiling process.

Comment: Sorry, it isn't coming back after compiling process, it comes back if I do a "maven update project configuration" or project -> clean ... (at the end of building workspace process the direcotry is filled again)

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed the same thing.  The easiest way to suppress them is to great a Resource filter.  Right click on your project and open Properties.  Then go to Resource -> Resource Filters.  Add a Exclude all Folder filter with "All children (recursive)" checked for "bin".  I also do the same for "target" to exclude the build directories.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's already maven project. there should be small M in top left of icon. If not right click on project, configure/convert to maven

now  Try right click on the project, maven/'update project'. After that retry removing the bin